# "What is an idiom?" vs. "What are idioms?"

Tags: meaning, differences

I often say

> What is an idiom?

When I read *[Longman Pocket Idioms Dictionary Cased](http://www.pearsonelt.com/products/Longman%20Pocket%20Idioms%20Dictionary%20Cased/9780582776418)*, I saw the sentence

> What are idioms?

Are there any differences between the two forms? Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 6):

*What are idioms?* and *What is an idiom?* are both grammatical and both more or less express the same idea. The indefinite article can be used to refer to any member of the class of things described by the following noun and that is how it is used in *What is an idiom?* It’s a common enough usage. We might also say *What is a poem?* or *What is a word?*

Comment: Purely my own opinion, but even though the two are (almost) identical in every context, I might be slightly more inclined to ask *"What are idioms?"* if I didn't have a clue, and wanted the quickest possible answer to give me a general idea. Whereas I might use *"What is an idiom?"* even if I already knew the general concept, but wanted to explore the definition in more detail.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: +1, because I suspect that's less an opinion and more a description of actual usage.

Answer (score 6):

*Idioms* and *an idiom* in the two questions posed are both grammatical. They are both ***[Generic Noun Phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html)***, which refer to classes and types of things, like *the tiger* in *The tiger is endangered*, which refers to the entire species.

Plural generic NPs (like *idioms* or *tigers*) and indefinite generic NPs (like *an idiom* or *a tiger*) are frequently encountered as predicate noun phrases, as in these two questions.

These questions **do** ask for slightly different answers, however. Indefinite generics are Definitions, so asking *What is an idiom?* is asking for a definition of the concept *idiom*. Plural generics, on the other hand, are about Norms, so asking *What are idioms?* can be interpreted as asking for a bunch of varied examples, perhaps with an added definition. You can make this sense clear by quantifying the plural generic noun with *some*: *What are some idioms?* unambiguously asks for a list.

In any event, it's the generic NPs that are important here, not the questions per se; generic Noun Phrases may appear in questions or statements of any kind, as may *[Generic Verb Phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html).*

Answer (score -3):

*What are Idioms* is more correct when compared to *what is an idiom*?
If a person raises a question to know the meaning of idioms, the more correct form is *what are idioms*? He will be talking about a number of idioms in general.
And if a person raise a question after mentioning a particular idiom, he may ask 
*what is an idiom*?

Comment: They are both equally correct. They are also very close to identical in meaning.

Answer (score -3):

When you say what is an idiom you're asking for the definition or meaning while asking what are idioms, you're asking for examples.

Comment: This may be a defensible view, but to defend it you would need to marshal an argument explaining why a reasonable person wouldn't interpret both questions as asking for a definition or meaning. If I wanted to ask someone for examples of idioms, I would ask "What are some examples of idioms?" not "What are idioms?"